# Calculate The Demographic Incidence By Age And Sex

Tags: r, count

Sample data

```
data = data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                  sex = c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
age1=c(10,10,16,10,10,13,16,16,12,11),
age2=c(12,12,18,12,12,15,18,18,14,13),
age3=c(14,14,20,14,14,17,20,20,16,15),
survey1=c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1),
survey2=c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1),
survey3=c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

long = reshape(data, direction = "long",
                            varying = list(c("age1","age2","age3"),c("survey1","survey2","survey3")),
                            v.names = c("age","survey"),
                            idvar = "id", timevar = "year", times = c(2000,2002,2004))
```

Here my Objective is to estimate the age specific incident rate that is specific for age and estimated separate by sex. I have larger data but this is a fake data.

I try to use "incidence" package

```
i.sex <- incidence(long, interval = 2, group = sex, event = survey)
```

but this do not work.

I see advice given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/889960/tim-riffe on a different but kind of related post if you have any advice. Thank you all

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by estimate, the link you havve posted is to someones profile.
`long %>% group_by(year, age, sex) %>% summarise(event = sum(survey, na.rm = TRUE))` is this kind of what you are looking for? From the `dplyr` package.

Comment: "estimate the age specific incident rate" means what? If you query `long` for id==1, you get three rows with survey all == 1. So is the answer in that case 3?  What's with the "interval" argument?